# Transpose a table using query in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the table1, i want to transpose it as shown in table1_1, can anyone tell me the query/function that can be used to do this

table 1

```
FileName    ObjectName  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5

F1           Line1         A       B       C      D       E
F1           Line2         F       G       H      I       J
F1           Line3         K       L       M      N       O


table1_1


FileName    ObjectName       Column    Data
F1            Line1          Column1    A
F1            Line1          Column2    B
F1            Line1          Column3    C
F1            Line1          Column4    D
F1            Line1          Column5    E
F1            Line2          Column1    F
F1            Line2          Column2    G
F1            Line2          Column3    H
F1            Line2          Column4    I
F1            Line2          Column5    J
F1            Line3          Column1    K
F1            Line3          Column2    L
F1            Line3          Column3    M
F1            Line3          Column4    N
F1            Line3          Column5    O
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [crosstab queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304348) used with Min, Max and Last.

Transpose:

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1_1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT Table1_1.FileName, Table1_1.ObjectName
FROM Table1_1
GROUP BY Table1_1.FileName, Table1_1.ObjectName
PIVOT Table1_1.Column;
```

Normalize:

```
SELECT FileName, ObjectName, "Column1" As ColName, Column1 As ColData  
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT FileName, ObjectName, "Column2" As ColName, Column2 As ColData  
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT FileName, ObjectName, "Column3" As ColName, Column3 As ColData  
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT FileName, ObjectName, "Column4" As ColName, Column4 As ColData  
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT FileName, ObjectName, "Column5" As ColName, Column5 As ColData  
FROM Table1
```

Comment: actually i want to do it using any query or function rather than using the wizard.

Comment: can you just help me by trying this out once

Comment: What is it you want me to do? You do not wish to use the wizard and you have not posted any attempt at SQL.

Comment: actually the thing is i tried the wizard but i am unable to get it exactly, i am getting confused in it. like how would i get the column names : Column1, Column2 etc in one column as data.

Comment: I have posted an example. You do not have to use the wizard, you can select crosstab as your query type from the options and add the necessary information to the query design grid.

Comment: I tried it, and it is working good if i implement it on Table1_1, but for Table1 it is getting dificult

Comment: Okay, I think we have a language problem. I think you mean you want to normalize.