# I want to assign the name of table1 in table 2 thanks

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
    UPDATE table1, (select top 1 [ID],chef,formateur,techni from table1 order by Num desc) 
AS x SET table2.ID = x.[ID], table2.Nom = x.[chef], table2.Nom = x.[formateur],
table2.Nom = x.[techni]
WHERE table2.mission="chef" and table2.mission="Formateur" and table2.mission="techni" ;

returns
table2                                            table 1
 ID | mission      |Nom|                ID |chef|Formateur|techni|   
 --------------------------------           ----------------------------
  1 |  chef        |   |                 1 |nom1|    nom2 | nom3|  
  2 |  Formateur   |   |               **Result**  
  3 |  techni      |   |                   ID | mission   | Nom|
                                         --------------------------  
                                            1 |  chef     | nom1|      
                                            2 |  Formateur| nom2|
                                            3 |  techni   | nom3|
```

1. I want to assign the name of table1 in table 2.
   Please i need your help :)

Comment: look at `join`s

Comment: im sorry i don't inderstand!!

Comment: read about SQL Joins.

Comment: please if you can edit my code help me please really i need your help

Comment: This looks like you need to do some type of crosstab query, since you want your columns to become rows.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210512/transpose-a-table-using-query-in-access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [What are SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: Not for example I just want the value of the last row that is in table 1 and copy it in table 2 for example it will affect chef = "name1" and Teacher = "name2", techni = "name3"

Comment: The problem is that I want to do several where in the same fields 2 conditions for the same fields you can see my request and you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data structure does not make sense. Table2 has only 3 records?

Your attempted example is updating Table1 when it appears you really want to update Table2. Why do you want to pull from just last record of Table1?

But try:

```
UPDATE Table2, 
(SELECT TOP 1 Table1.ID, Table1.chef, Table1.formateur, Table1.techni
FROM Table1 ORDER BY Table1.ID DESC) AS Q 
SET Table2.nom = Switch([mission]="chef",[chef],[mission]="formateur",[formateur],[mission]="techni",[techni]);
```

Comment: really thank you very very very much you are the best