# Transpose a table using a query in MS Access withVBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, transpose

I have a table in the form:

```
ID        Task/Title        StartDate        EndDate

1           Title1             
2           TaskA              X                X
3           TaskB              X                X
4           TaskC              X                X
5           Title2             
6           TaskA              V                V
7           TaskB              V                V
8           TaskC              V                V
```

And I want to transform it into something similar to:

```
Title  SrtDate-TskA  StpDate-TskA  SrtDate-TskB  StpDate-TskB  SrtDate-TskC  StpDate-TskC

Title1      X             X             X              X             X             X
Title2      V             V             V              V             V             V
```

I was trying to use the [Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql) method like I saw mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210512/transpose-a-table-using-query-in-access?newreg=6798d3ca41fa4287b035f5b23adec695) question and answer, but I cannot seem to get it right. Any pointers in the right direction? Or am I out of luck on this one and need to find another way?

Comment: That Q&A is not relevant since requirement is to normalize data whereas you want to de-normalize. But your data structure is not appropriate for CROSSTAB either because there is no way to know that ID 2 TaskA belongs with Title1 other than by trusting the ID sort order. Data structure as displayed is flawed. Yes, VBA can likely handle it if can rely on ID field to properly order records.

Comment: You're looking to create a "pivot table". A table which has both row and column headers.  Searching google on "microsoft access how to create a pivot table" yields this link: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/instead-of-queries-use-the-access-2007-pivottable-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most anything can be done with enough code. Assuming sample dataset accurately represents entire table, here is one approach that requires to first normalize data structure. Each record needs a Title group identifier. Add a field in table for group identifier and populate it with VBA. Like:

```
Sub SetTitleGrp()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, intT As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If IsNull(rs!StartDate) Then intT = rs!ID
    rs.Edit
    rs!TitleGrp = intT
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Then a query:

```
SELECT Table1.TitleGrp, Titles.Task_Title AS Title,
    IIf([StartDate] Is Null, Null, Table1.[Task_Title]) AS Task, 
    Table1.StartDate, Table1.EndDate FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TitleGrp, Task_Title FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate Is Null) AS Titles 
ON Titles.TitleGrp = Table1.TitleGrp
WHERE Not StartDate is null;
```

Produces normalized dataset:

```
    TitleGrp    Title   Task    StartDate    EndDate
    1           Title1  TaskA       x           x
    1           Title1  TaskB       x           x
    1           Title1  TaskC       x           x
    5           Title2  TaskA       v           v
    5           Title2  TaskB       v           v
    5           Title2  TaskC       v           v
```

Use that dataset in CROSSTAB query.

```
TRANSFORM Max(Query1.StartDate) AS MaxOfStartDate
SELECT Query1.TitleGrp, Query1.Title
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.TitleGrp, Query1.Title
PIVOT "StrtDate-" & [Task];
```

However, transform on two fields (StartDate and EndDate) complicates. Do another CROSSTAB for EndDate. Then a query that JOINS the two CROSSTAB queries.

Access2010 can build a Pivot Table with this normalized dataset or export to Excel and do a pivot there.

An alternative approach could involve opening and reading recordset and writing records to a 'temp' table (table is permanent but records are temporary). Table would be normalized structure or get really complicated with code and write to table structured in the desired final output.

Comment: This is amazing. I don't know if I could have worked through this without your help, it means a lot. Does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you really like it, you can upvote as well.

Comment: I did! Just not enough rep to display it. On a related note, if I wanted to take the final combined query and add the StrtDate and StpDate to another table that has the same titles (so the title would be the IDs) could that be easily through an update query? Or would I need to turn the query into a table first?
Just to update one field I was expecting something like this to work:

`UPDATE TableToUpdate
INNER JOIN CombinedQuery ON TableToUpdate.[Title] = CombinedQuery.[Title] SET TableToUpdate.[StartDate-A] = CombinedQuery.[StartDate-A];`

Comment: Could probably increase rep enough if you visited help center and reviewed some of the FAQ's https://stackoverflow.com/help. Don't think UPDATE will work with CROSSTAB. CROSSTAB is not an editable query and UPDATE requires an editable query. Try it and find out. But why save to a table when it can be calculated when needed?

Comment: Because this table that I am manipulating is being imported from the users computer and then it would update the main table that is shared among all the users. But you are correct, doesn't seem like you can update it. So I will give creating a table from the combined query a try.

Comment: Why is user data in such a bizarre structure?

Comment: It is the format that Microsoft Project exports excel documents in. Seems to all be working great now.